# Handsontable: Edit epoch timestamps as dates

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'd like to edit a date cell in a Handsontable which is provided as epoch timestamp. I managed to use a formatter to display the cells as date/times, but I struggle with editing the cells as dates (ideally as datetime picker, but that's another topic, for now it would suffice to see a date/time when the cell enters edit mode). Instead of the integer value, I'd like to get the formatted sting when entering cell edit mode (and convert to epoch when leaving enter mode, so the underlying data remains in this format).

[image]

Comment: is this still of interest? Have you tried to create a custom editor? https://handsontable.com/docs/5.0.0/tutorial-cell-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

Handsontable has a `date` cell type:
https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/demo-date.html